# Properties of Burnside Groups

Tags: group-theory

Like in Number Theory, there are many problems in Group Theory which are easy to state to anyone but difficult to solve; one among them is Burnsides problem: *If a group $B_{m,n}$ is generated by $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_m$, subject to the relations that $x^n=1$ for all elements $x$ in group, then is $B_{m,n}$ a finite group?*

There is interesting history and work on this problem (see, for example, just the *introduction* in the article *Periodic groups of odd exponents: S. I. Adyan*). When I looked some results about this group, immediately, I asked myself, *how can we prove this (these results)*? It turns out that many proofs of some results on group $B_{m,n}$ are difficult or lengthy.

Then my question is

**Question:** What are interesting properties of the group $B_{m,n}$ which are easy to prove?

Comment: I think you have the wrong (or rather, too few) relations. It should be $x^n = 1$ for all $x$, not just for the generators.

Comment: Thank you Tobias; I was wrong, it is corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proofs that $B_{m,3}$ and $B_{m,4}$ are finite are reasonably accessible, and can be covered in an advanced undergraduate course in group theory. The proof that $B_{m,6}$ is finite is harder but still readable - it's in Marshall Hall's book on Group Theory.

I think all of the infiniteness proofs are extremely long and difficult, as is the proof of the Restricted Burnside Problem, which resulted in a Fields Medal for Zelmanov.

There is also an interesting  algorithm (the $p$-quotient algorithm)  for computing the largest finite quotients.

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer; is there a survey article on Burnside groups or Burnsides problem?

Comment: I would start with  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_problem

Answer (score 2):

Burnside himself proved some easy cases in his paper, namely

$\bullet$ $B(1, n)$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, and hence finite.

$\bullet$ $B(m, 2)$ is the direct product of $m$ copies of the cyclic group of order $2$ and hence finite.